# Bootstrap 3 MVC 5 jQuery-ui Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get Autocomplete working in a Bootstrap 3 project on a Modal window using the basic example:

```
$("#txtTest").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

CSS is not my strongest area and I've now spent a while googling this, as you can see the Autocomplete items are on a transparent background.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28316339/bootstrap3-jqueryui.autocomplete.png

I added this which at least got the text on top:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 10000000;
}
```

Using JQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery-UI 1.10.4

Should I abandon jQuery-ui Autocomplete and try Twitter Typeahead?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the CSS file that comes with jquery-ui: jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css